# Python set to /usr/local/bin/python how to set to /usr/bin/python

Tags: python, macos

I made the mistake of installing **python 2.7.6** without using home brew and now my python is set to the python in `/usr/local/bin/python` (which is 2.7.6).

I want to get rid of python 2.7.6 and change my default python to the standard system python 2.7.5 in `/usr/bin/python`.

How do I do this?

Answer (score -1):

Did you take a look at [this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4393830/how-do-i-set-up-a-local-python-library-directory-pythonpath?rq=1) I assume you are using bash shell.So you can put

```
PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:/usr/bin/python"
```

in your `~/.bash_profile`. For me , I use `zsh`. So I place it in `~/.zshrc`.