# ImportError: No module named PyQt4

Tags: python, pyqt4, homebrew

I installed pyqt4 by using Homebrew. But when I import PyQt4 in python interpreter, It said that "No module named PyQt4". Can somebody help me with that?

Comment: Have you installed additional Python versions besides Apple's? If so, which ones? And which of them gets run when you just type `python` at the shell? (Generally, PyQt4 and similar packages on Homebrew can only work with Apple's Python or a Homebrew-built Python, not with, say, a Python.org or Enthought or ActiveState Python. Also, if you have two different Python 2.7 installations, it's very easy to install something to one site-packages, and then try to use it from the other, and not even realize you're doing anything wrong.)

Comment: I think this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961997/is-it-possible-to-add-pyqt4-pyside-packages-on-a-virtualenv-sandbox will help you. I do this, and it works.

Answer (score 23):

After `brew install pyqt`, you can `brew test pyqt` which will use the python you have got in your PATH in oder to do the test (show a Qt window).

For non-brewed Python, you'll have to set your PYTHONPATH as `brew info pyqt` will tell.

Sometimes it is necessary to open a new shell or tap in order to use the freshly brewed binaries.

I frequently check these issues by printing the sys.path from inside of python:
`python -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"`
The `$(brew --prefix)/lib/pythonX.Y/site-packages` have to be in the `sys.path` in order to be able to import stuff. As said, for brewed python, this is default but for any other python, you will have to set the `PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: Thank you. After running 'brew info pyqt', it gives you the commands you need to set the path correctly.

Answer (score 14):

You have to check which Python you are using. I had the same problem because the Python I was using was not the same one that brew was using. In your command line:

1. `which python`
   output: /usr/bin/python
2. `which brew`
   output: /usr/local/bin/brew          //so they are different
3. `cd /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`
4. `ls`     //you can see PyQt4 and sip are here
5. Now you need to add `usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages` to your python path.
6. `open ~/.bash_profile`     //you will open your bash_profile file in your editor
7. Add   `'export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH'`     to your bash file and save it
8. Close your terminal and restart it to reload the shell
9. `python`
10. `import PyQt4`    // it is ok now

Answer (score 11):

If you're using Anaconda to manage Python on your system, you can install it with:

`$ conda install pyqt=4`

Omit the `=4` to install the most current version.

Answer from [How to install PyQt4 in anaconda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21637922/how-to-install-pyqt4-in-anaconda)

Answer (score 5):

I solved the same problem for my own program by installing `python3-pyqt4`.

I'm not using Python 3 but it still helped.

Answer (score 4):

It is likely that you are running the python executable from /usr/bin (Apple version) instead of /usr/loca/bin (Brew version)

You can either

a) check your PATH variable

or

b) run `brew doctor`

or

c) run `which python`

to check if it is the case.