# Install Python package: "Package missing in current win-64 channels"

Tags: python, package, anaconda, conda

I want to install GSEApy on Anaconda (I use 64bit Windows 10).
https://bioconda.github.io/recipes/gseapy/README.html
https://anaconda.org/bioconda/gseapy

But I get this error:

```
C:\Windows\system32>conda install gseapy

Using Anaconda Cloud api site https:// api.anaconda.org
Fetching package metadata ...........
Solving package specifications: .
Error: Package missing in current win-64 channels:
  - gseapy

You can search for packages on anaconda.org with
anaconda search -t conda gseapy
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: I was getting this error when trying to install PyQt4 by running `conda install pyqt4` However later I find out on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21637922/how-to-install-pyqt4-in-anaconda I just need to use `conda install pyqt=4` Then it worked wonderfully. It as for the both 32 and 64 bits Anaconda versions.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to use a channel that has a win-64 version. Use:

```
conda install -c bioninja gseapy
```

The option `-c` or `--channel` allows to specify a channel.
You can also add a channel permanently via:

```
conda config --add channels bioninja
```

This creates a file `.condarc` in your home directory (on Windows `C:\Users\<username>`):

```
channels:
  - bioninja
  - defaults
```

You can modify this file manually. The order of the channels determines
their precedence.

**Note**: Files with a leading `.` might not be displayed 
by certain file browsers. You might need to change settings to display these
files accordingly.

You can find out if a package exits for your platform by searching on [Anaconda](https://anaconda.org/). Just type `gseapy` in the search field and you should see the [available packages](https://anaconda.org/search?q=gseapy). The column "Platforms" shows if a "win-64" version exists.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, it worked. I didn´t know how to choose a specific channel.

Comment: Great that it helped. BTW, you can [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) an answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: The order of the channels maters. Conda will go through the channels as listed in the config-file `.condarc`. As soon as it finds a package in a channel, it takes it. For example, if you put `defaults` first and `cond-forge` later it will prefer packages from the default Anaconda channel over the cond-forge ones. Reverse the order for the opposite effect.

Answer (score 1):

Now you could install lastest gseapy through bioconda, too

```
conda install -c bioconda gseapy
```

Comment: But the `bioconda` channel/owner doesn't have a `win-64` version of `gseapy` (as of the time of this posting), [right? -- check this screenshot](http://imgur.com/k345YTc)

Answer (score 1):

Check the latest version of Keras from the Anaconda Cloud website

https://anaconda.org/search?q=keras

Use command:

```
conda install -c conda-forge keras=<version>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it need you to specify a detalied version,so you can just find a version support your environment in Anaconda Clound,just a line of command like "conda install -c dhirschfeld protobuf=3.0.0a3.post418+g0cb84ee ",I select this and it works.