# Repair broken conda

Tags: anaconda

when doing this

```
conda install c anaconda idna=2.2
```

I have this and conda cannot find :

```
Fetching package metadata .........
Solving package specifications: .

    PackageNotFoundError: Package not found:
 '' Package missing in current win-64 channels:
      - c
```

However, you can see this in Win64 channels...
https://anaconda.org/anaconda/idna/files

Comment: Maybe this be help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38739694/install-python-package-package-missing-in-current-win-64-channels and this https://github.com/conda-forge/leveldb-feedstock/issues/2

Answer (score 1):

It's probably clear after Vladimir's comment but you can just do `conda install idna=2.2`. The packages in the `anaconda` channel are in the default channel so you don't need to use the channel name. If you want to specify the channel name then you can use `-c` or `--channel` like `conda install -c anaconda idna=2.2`.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
 conda install -c conda-forge idna
```