# Issue while installing Tensorflow in Windows 10 (python 3.6.2)

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, tensorflow, conda

While I am executing the following command it errors out:

```
<><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><>
(tensorflow36) C:\Users\usr1>conda install tensorflow
Fetching package metadata .................

PackageNotFoundError: Packages missing in current channels:

  - tensorflow
```

We have searched for the packages in the following channels:

- http://conda.anaconda.org/gurobi/win-32
- http://conda.anaconda.org/gurobi/noarch
- https://conda.anaconda.org/anaconda-fusion/win-32
- https://conda.anaconda.org/anaconda-fusion/noarch
- https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/win-32
- https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/noarch
- https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/noarch
- https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/win-32

What am I missing??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Install Python package: "Package missing in current win-64 channels"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38739694/install-python-package-package-missing-in-current-win-64-channels)

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the docs (https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows):

> within Anaconda, we recommend installing TensorFlow with the pip
>   install command, not with the conda install command.

**CPU-only version:**

```
pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-0.12.1-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
```

**GPU version:**

```
pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/gpu/tensorflow_gpu-0.12.1-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
```

The --upgrade option of pip will make sure the newest available version of tensorflow gets installed. For more info go to **Pip installation on Windows** in https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/get_started/os_setup

Comment: Thank you for your response, it is much appreciated! Here is the latest. See below the issue: <><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><>
C:\Users\ths>activate tensorflow36

(tensorflow36) C:\Users\ths>pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade tensorflow
Collecting tensorflow
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for tensorflow

(tensorflow36) C:\Users\ths>
<><><><><><>?><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><> BTW, this is MS Windows 10 environment.

Comment: Do you have an Nvidia GPU?

Comment: Okay, I've modified my answer. Hope it helps you!

Comment: Thank you!  Does the name 'tensorflow-0.12.1-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl' mean that I will install TensorFlow versio 0.12??

Comment: I just tried the latest install tensorflow command (pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-0.12.1-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl) but it errors out: << tensorflow-0.12.1-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.>> My laptop runs on Intel's Corei7 CPU!!!

Comment: Are you sure the wheel you tried is the CPU one? Just wondering...You can try to install a later wheel from here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tensorflow/1.3.0 or you can also make your own CPU-only wheel as indicated here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/r0.12/tensorflow/contrib/cmake

Comment: Can you please do pip --version and tell us the output

Comment: Here is the output: (tensorflow36) C:\Users\ths>pip --version
pip 9.0.1 from C:\Users\ths\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow36\lib\site-packages (python 3.6)

Comment: There is a chance you are trying to install the 64 bit version of Tensorflow on a 32 bit Python installation. Could you execute the following command in your Python interpreter to see which version of Python you have: import struct;print(struct.calcsize("P") * 8)

Comment: Yes, I do have a 32 -bit Python installation. To be exact, here is the detailed description: "Python 3.6.2 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Jul 20 2017, 13:00:41) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32"

Comment: If you can't get a 32 bit version of tensorflow, you might need a 64 bit version of python to make it work.