# Receiving an error in Conda prompt when trying to install jira

Tags: python, anaconda, jira

I'm new to Python and Anaconda. Trying to install the jira package through conda using "conda install jira" and here's the output I get. I've also tried the pip install in the command prompt.

```
(C:\Program Files\Anaconda2) C:\Windows\system32>conda install jira
Fetching package metadata ...Could not connect to https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/win-64/
Could not connect to https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/win-64/
..Could not connect to https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch/
.Could not connect to https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch/
.
Solving package specifications: .
Error: Package missing in current win-64 channels:
  - jira

You can search for packages on anaconda.org with

    anaconda search -t conda jira

(C:\Program Files\Anaconda2) C:\Windows\system32>
```

Comment: There are different channels for certain package: did you try `conda install -c conda-forge jira`. But `conda install jira` worked for me. check the potential duplicate below.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Install Python package: "Package missing in current win-64 channels"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38739694/install-python-package-package-missing-in-current-win-64-channels)

Comment: Error shows Conda can't connect to the sites. Are you behind a proxy? @mmustafaicer, the package definitely is available as you point out, but OP can't read the channels to begin with, so not really an appropriate duplicate.