# No module named PyQt4 in python 3.6 when I use matplotlib.pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt4, ubuntu-16.04, python-3.6

When I import `matplotlib.pyplot` in any python 3.6 program, I get the following error:

`$ python kernel1.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "kernel1.py", line 13, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "/home/atul/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 115, in <module>
    _backend_mod, new_figure_manager, draw_if_interactive, _show = pylab_setup()
  File "/home/atul/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/__init__.py", line 32, in pylab_setup
    globals(),locals(),[backend_name],0)
  File "/home/atul/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt5agg.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .backend_qt5 import QtCore
  File "/home/atul/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt5.py", line 26, in <module>
    import matplotlib.backends.qt_editor.figureoptions as figureoptions
  File "/home/atul/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/qt_editor/figureoptions.py", line 20, in <module>
    import matplotlib.backends.qt_editor.formlayout as formlayout
  File "/home/atul/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/qt_editor/formlayout.py", line 56, in <module>
    from matplotlib.backends.qt_compat import QtGui, QtWidgets, QtCore
  File "/home/atul/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/qt_compat.py", line 137, in <module>
    from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt4'`

However, if I use python 3.5, `matplotlib.pyplot` works perfectly.

I have tried using `sudo apt-get install python-qt4`. Still I get the same error.

I am using Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: From the error message that I see that you are using anaconda so install pyqt4 with apt-get does not work, you must use anaconda to install pyqt4

Comment: read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21637922/how-to-install-pyqt4-in-anaconda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to downgrade to PyQt4 from PyQt5 at the command line within the relevant environment:

```
conda install pyqt=4
```

This will downgrade other packages as well.  You may need to think about using PyQt5 if this will cause you other problems when using Python 3.6.

Also, Continuum do not support this version for Python 3.6+.  Please see [this GitHub page](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/2682) for confirmation.

Answer (score 1):

For python 3.6(since i had that in my computer), you go to command line , and type this :

conda install -c anaconda pyqt=5.6.0

If you are unsure about the python and pyqt version. Then type :

conda info pyqt

This will output the relevant pyqt version. Hence you can check your pyqt version and install from command mentioned at first.

Comment: After I install this, I get the following error:                                                    $ python
Python 3.6.0 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Dec 23 2016, 12:22:00) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
[1]    5177 segmentation fault (core dumped)  python

Answer (score 0):

One command saved me:

```
conda update ipython
```