# How Can I Install PyQT4 alongside PyQT5 with anaconda?

Tags: python, pyqt

I'm using pyqt5 for long time as it comes with anaconda pre-installed , but Heard somewhere that PyQt4 contains a GPL Exception but PyQT5 doesn't so I want use pyqt4

Comment: Where did you hear that PyQt4 contains a GPL Exception?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install PyQt4 in anaconda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21637922/how-to-install-pyqt4-in-anaconda)

Comment: Yes, PyQt4 can be installed next to PyQt5.

Comment: @eyllanesc i found about GPL Exception from these sources https://askubuntu.com/questions/339723/can-i-sell-my-pyqt4-app-without-having-a-pyqt-license and https://github.com/Werkov/PyQt4/blob/master/GPL_EXCEPTION.TXT