# How do I download a previous version of aiottp?

Tags: python, discord.py, aiohttp

I'm coding a discord bot and when installing some packages my cmd said I got this error

> "discord-py 1.0.0a1634+g7f4c57d has requirement aiohttp<3.5.0,>=3.3.0,
>   but you'll have aiohttp 3.5.4 which is incompatible."

I tried installing aiohttp 3.5.0 but when installing the package it said

> "discord-py 1.0.0a1634+g7f4c57d has requirement aiohttp<3.5.0,>=3.3.0,
>   but you'll have aiohttp 3.5.5 which is incompatible."

and then my cmd `uninstalled aiohttp 3.5.0` and

> reinstalled aiohttp 3.5.4

How do I fix this?

Comment: What platform/installer are you using? Anaconda perhaps?

Comment: At first you should show us how you installed it and what versions of Python and `pip` (?) are involved.

Comment: If so, this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40920535/2988730

Comment: Hi @ThanosaurusRex, welcome to Stack Overflow. I suggest you take a look at Stack Overflow's article on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). As-is, your question is formatted in a way that makes it really difficult to read. The [formatting documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) might also help you out. The clearer you are able to explain your problem, the more likely it is that someone can help you out.

Answer (score 1):

With pip like @bgsuello said:

```
pip install aiohttp==3.4
```

With conda

```
conda install aiohttp=3.4
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```sh
pip install aiohttp==3.4
```