# How to run pyside_postinstall.py on virtualenv copy of PySide?

Tags: python, virtualenv, pyside

I get the following error when attempting to run a virtualenv ipython on the qt gui:

```
ImportError: libpyside-python2.7.so.1.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

To 'install' PySide on my virtualenv I just copied over system built PySide from `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` to the virtual environment's `site-packages`. I understand the post installation script does the dynamic linking. This obviously works for the system installed PySide package but how do I run post installation similarly for the virtualenv copied libs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see the detailed howto on PyPI: [Installing PySide distribution into virtual Python environment](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PySide#id7)

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend following the solution described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961997/is-it-possible-to-add-pyqt4-pyside-packages-on-a-virtualenv-sandbox). Basically:

```
source $VIRTUALENV/bin/activate
easy_install PySide
python $VIRTUALENV/bin/pyside_postinstall.py -install
```

and see if that helps.

Comment: Christian is right. And you can also install PySide via pip, which will call the post-install script automatically: $VIRTUALENV/bin/pip install PySide

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by [rlacko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2052118/rlacko)...

Ubuntu specific:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential git cmake libqt4-dev libphonon-dev python2.7-dev libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev qtmobility-dev
sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

No longer Ubuntu-specific. Install/create a virtualenv:

```
sudo pip install virtualenv
virtualenv myVirtualEnv
```

Install PySide into the virtualenv:

```
source myVirtualEnv/bin/activate
sudo myVirtualEnv/bin/pip install PySide
```

Open the Python command prompt:

```
myVirtualEnv/bin/python
```

In the Python prompt, attempt to import QtGui from PySide:

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from PySide import QtGui
>>>
```

If you don't see any errors, you're all good.

Answer (score -1):

Few more steps required for Linux, [found here](http://transmissionboards.com/tech/install-ipython-virtualenv-sandbox-linux-t269.html)