# How to install SIP and PyQt on a virtual environment?

Tags: python, pyqt, virtualenv

I am new to `virtualenv`. I want to install spyder, which require `PyQt4`, which requires `SIP`.

`pip` doesn't work, so I downloaded `SIP`, and I did the following commands:

```
python configure.py
make
make install
```

But I received this error:

```
make[1]: entrant dans le répertoire « /stck2/stck2.2/ptoniato/python/pip/virtualenv-1.10.1/provaenv/build/SIP/sipgen »
cp -f sip /stck2/stck2.2/ptoniato/python/pip/virtualenv-1.10.1/provaenv/bin/sip
make[1]: quittant le répertoire « /stck2/stck2.2/ptoniato/python/pip/virtualenv-1.10.1/provaenv/build/SIP/sipgen »
make[1]: entrant dans le répertoire « /stck2/stck2.2/ptoniato/python/pip/virtualenv-1.10.1/provaenv/build/SIP/siplib »
cp -f sip.so /stck2/stck2.2/ptoniato/python/pip/virtualenv-1.10.1/provaenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sip.so
strip /stck2/stck2.2/ptoniato/python/pip/virtualenv-1.10.1/provaenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sip.so
cp -f /stck2/stck2.2/ptoniato/python/pip/virtualenv-1.10.1/provaenv/build/SIP/siplib/sip.h /usr/local/python/include/python2.7/sip.h
cp: impossible de supprimer « /usr/local/python/include/python2.7/sip.h »: Permission non accordée
make[1]: *** [install] Erreur 1
make[1]: quittant le répertoire « /stck2/stck2.2/ptoniato/python/pip/virtualenv-1.10.1/provaenv/build/SIP/siplib »
make: *** [install] Erreur 2
```

Impossible de supprimer means Impossible to erase.

I have no root access to this pc. I think that's there is a conflict between the python package that is installed by default on this pc and the `virtualenv` that I am creating.

How can I resolve the problem?

Comment: Just follow this Link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961997/is-it-possible-to-add-pyqt4-pyside-packages-on-a-virtualenv-sandbox

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here are the steps I used to install sip in my virtualenv. The trick is to make sure that you use the (undocumented?) `--always-copy` flag, so that it doesn't just *symlink* the `/usr/include/python2.7` directory into your `virtualenv`.

```
virtualenv --always-copy ve
. ve/bin/activate
wget http://sourceforge.net/projects/pyqt/files/sip/sip-4.15.4/sip-4.15.4.zip
unzip sip-4.15.4.zip
cd sip-4.15.4
python configure.py --incdir=../ve/include/python2.7
make
make install
cd ..
```

I was then able to install PyQt4 like so:

```
wget http://sourceforge.net/projects/pyqt/files/PyQt4/PyQt-4.10.3/PyQt-x11-gpl-4.10.3.tar.gz
tar zxvf PyQt-x11-gpl-4.10.3.tar.gz
cd PyQt-x11-gpl-4.10.3
python configure.py
make
make install
```

This did give an error at the end, but it was ignored. I think this is just part of installing 'designer' which isn't critical.

```
install: cannot create regular file `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/plugins/designer/libpyqt4.so': Permission denied
make[1]: [install_target] Error 1 (ignored)
```

Comment: Using Ubuntu 14.10, python3.4 and last version of sip and pyqt at the time of sriting this, I had to use an absolute path for incdir while compiling sip (/home/username/.virtualenvs/ve/include/python3.4). For PyQt I had to use the --sip-incdir option with the same (absolute) path.
Also, grab some coffee and a bit of patience since PyQt is __big__ it took a while to compile over here.

Comment: I'd like to add that the --incdir part of "python configure.py --incdir..." is what was necessary for me to remove the "permission denied errors," and also resulted in "import sipconfig" and "import sip" working. When "--incdir.." was omitted, only "import sip" worked

Comment: Hey all! I am trying to do this install in a virtualenv but am running into an issue. The SIP install went ok. I install SIP version 4.19.2. When I go to run configure for PyQt 4.12, I get the error "Error: This version of PyQt requires SIP v4.19.0 or later". I tried running with --incdir set to the include dir without success. Am I missing a step?

Answer (score 7):

make sure that you have your virtualenv active.
With both pyenv and pyenv-virtualenv installed you can quickly follow these commands.

I just installed both SIP and PyQt4 succesfully on a newly created virtualenv:

```
pyenv virtualenv testenvironment
pyenv rehash
pyenv shell testenvironment
cd ~/.pyenv/versions/testenvironment/
pip install --no-install sip #fails but do not worry
cd build/sip/
python configure.py #--incdir=~/.pyenv/versions/testenvironment/include/python2.7 may be needed
make
make install
cd ../../
```

Then you are ready to download and install PyQt4. You have to do it
manually.
Go to the [PyQt4 page](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/download) and get
the latest version in the working folder, unpack it and you are ready to go
again with configure/make/make install.

Test if by importing some PyQt4 packages in a python interactive session:

```
>>> from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
```