# Macport Portfiles do not work in Virtualenv

Tags: python, qt, python-2.7, pyqt, virtualenv

I have installed PyQt4 through Macport `sudo port install py27-pyqt4` and virtualenv with `pip install virtualenv`. Whenever I run my PyQt programs while i am in the virtual environment I would receive the following error:

```
ImportError: No module named PyQt4.QtGui
```

However, I am able to run the same application when I am out of the virtual environment. What could be the reason for this issue and how do I resolve it?

Comment: Did you activate the virtualenv and install the library while having it activated?

Comment: no i did not. I have tried recreating the virtualenv environment after installing the library, but the error continues to propagate.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you may have not installed PyQt4 into the virtual environment, usually the steps are as follows:

1) Create a virtual env: `virtualenv ve_name`

2) Activate the created virtualenv: `source path_to_ve_name/bin/activate` (at this point your shell will get `ve_name` prepended to it, and your `$PATH` will get updated, so whatever you install via pip will end up going into `path_to_ve_name/bin`)

3) Install all the dependencies while keeping `ve_name` active: `pip install package-name`, etc.

Once you have done this, you need to install PyQt4 into that virtual environment, there's an example here: [How to install SIP and PyQt on a virtual environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19856927/how-to-install-sip-and-pyqt-on-a-virtual-environment) It looks like a simple `pip install` doesn't work with PyQT, so check out the suggestions in that question.

When you are done dealing with `ve_name`, you just need to `deactivate` your virtual environment (using command `deactivate` from your shell). This will revert your $PATH variable, and you can either create a new ve for a new project, or resume working on the same project by reactivating the created ve.