# virtualenv's python can't find PyQt4

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4, virtualenv

Running OSX (10.8.2) here, replaced their python with Homebrew's.  All good:

`$ which python
/usr/local/bin/python`

Installed pip, virtualenv with brew python.  Installed pyqt with brew.

If I

```
$ python
>>> import PyQt4
```

, no problems.  However, if I

```
(env)$ python
>>> import PyQt4
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named PyQt4
```

Why can't the virtualenv python environment see my system-wide install of pyqt?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to add PyQt4/PySide packages on a Virtualenv sandbox?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961997/is-it-possible-to-add-pyqt4-pyside-packages-on-a-virtualenv-sandbox)

Comment: Check the solution from the link above, and if it works please delete your question, or else update your post with the results. Not closing now only because that question is 5 years old.