# Need yum to use virutalenv's python. 'yum install PyQt4' uses system's python.

Tags: python, pyqt, virtualenv, yum

'yum install PyQt4' uses system's python2.6 even when the virtualenv is activated. I want yum to install PyQt4 for virutalenv's python. Kindly help me. I am using CentOs.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you can't install it with pip so here the official documentation sorry about that. So yeah i think you have to install it by hand.

Or According to this topic: [PyQt on virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961997/is-it-possible-to-add-pyqt4-pyside-packages-on-a-virtualenv-sandbox) You should be able to simply copy/sym link the contents to your virtualenv after your yum installation.

[Installing PyQt4](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/installation.html)

Comment: When I execute pip install pyqt4, I get the message: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyqt4 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pyqt4. Thats why I asked wrt yum.