# No module named pygtk in virtualenv with Ubuntu 14.04 and Python 2.7.6

Tags: python, virtualenv, pygtk

I created an virtualenv with virtualenvwrapper:

> ```
> mkvirtualenv test --no-site-packages
> workon test
> cdvirtualenv
> ```

Then I created a simple script named testme.py:

> ```
> #!/usr/bin/env python
> import pygtk
> ```

Result:

> ```
> $ python testme.py 
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "testme.py", line 3, in <module>
>     import pygtk
> ImportError: No module named pygtk
> ```

I tried this now many times and different ways but nothing worked...

Here is what I have done already:

1. Try to install it with pip:

> ```
> Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1
> ```

2. Install ruamel.venvgtk inside the virtualenv (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ruamel.venvgtk/0.4.1)
3. Link it directly (and add path):

> ```
> mkdir -p lib/python2.7/dist-packages/
> ln -s /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0 lib/python2.7/dist-packages/
> ln -s /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gobject lib/python2.7/dist-packages/
> ln -s /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/glib lib/python2.7/dist-packages/
> ln -s /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cairo lib/python2.7/dist-packages/
> add2virtualenv  lib/python2.7/dist-packages/
> ```

4. Link it to the site-packages from sys.path:

> ```
> ln -s /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0 lib/python2.7/site-packages/
> ln -s /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gobject lib/python2.7/site-packages/
> ln -s /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/glib lib/python2.7/site-packages/
> ln -s /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cairo lib/python2.7/site-packages/
> ```

I tried it now so many time. Could get it run 1 time, but could not reproduce it.

**edit:** I forgot to link pygtk itself.

> ln -s /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pygtk.py
>   lib/python2.7/site-packages/

Comment: You can use your system packages within `virtualenv` you need to create a new virtual environement using `mkvirtualenv environment  --system-site-packages`.

Comment: Thank you, I forgot to say that I need it without "system-site-packages"

Comment: Ok i'll post the solution and you can upvote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is how it works now for me:**

> ```
> mkvirtualenv test --no-site-packages
> workon test
> cdvirtualenv
>
>
> ln -s /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0 lib/python2.7/site-packages/
> ln -s /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gobject lib/python2.7/site-packages/
> ln -s /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/glib lib/python2.7/site-packages/
> ln -s /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cairo lib/python2.7/site-packages/
> ln -s /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pygtk.py lib/python2.7/site-packages/
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use your system packages within `virtualenv` you need to create a new virtual environement using `mkvirtualenv environment --system-site-packages`

Comment: Thank you, I forgot to say that I need it without "system-site-packages"

Comment: You can try this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9064289/installing-pygtk-in-virtualenv).