Is there any way to optimize disk usage for virtualenv environments?
I have several virtualenvs for the same Python version, each with a physical copy of each dependency file. Some AI-related dependencies (tensorflow, torch, nvidia, etc) tend to be immense.
As a consequence, a lot of disk space is consumed with a lot of duplicate files.
I'm looking for a way to optimize disk usage by symlinking files or sharing environments differently.
It might be something when creating the environments, or maybe after and just a file system operation level.
This is not the same as in How to share libraries between virtual environments and/or python installation, since using "--system-site-packages" will limit to a single version of a dependency per Python version (which at some point seems to be most correct thing). But I would prefer to have the flexibility to have several versions.
For instance, here are 3 virtualenvs with similar dependencies

More disk consuming dependencies:


Have you considered this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/36594499/6055465

Yes. Although is not exactly what I'm looking for. "--system-site-packages" will limit to a single version of a dependency per Python version (since I'm using pyenv) ...which seems to be correct in the end. But I would prefer to have the flexibility to have several versions.

Using something like fdupes or rdfind is closer to what I was looking -> https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/428377/78466

I think conda packaging ecosystem does this. By this I mean the "deduplication" thing, where if a dependency is installed in 2+ environments it takes only disk space once (not 2+). In the "normal" PyPA/PyPI based ecosystem, I think maybe uv does this, I am not sure.

Nice! Somehow, I was never capable of joining the conda world (somehow, I always felt some sort of negation towards it). I will look into uv's approach to be more informed.

You might consider doing this at the filesystem layer and not having any code or configuration above the system administration level involved at all. I've been a happy user of (and package maintainer on NixOS for) bees for many years.

...and speaking of NixOS, it arguably takes some of the principles of uv described above further than uv itself does, as described in detail in https://edolstra.github.io/pubs/phd-thesis.pdf. (Not that the tools can't be used together -- uv2nix is a thing that exists).
