# VirtualEnv with empty `pip freeze` using `--no-site-packages` -- how to?

Tags: python, ubuntu, virtualenv

So, this answer is, in theory, already out there. However, after reading a [bunch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6627035/why-does-pip-freeze-report-some-packages-in-a-fresh-virtualenv-created-with-no)  [of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249283/virtualenv-on-ubuntu-with-no-site-packages)  [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382925/virtualenv-no-site-packages-and-pip-still-finding-global-packages) on SO, I am still at a loss of how exactly to get a fresh / clean virtualenv up and running. The problem appears to be some variation on the fact that I have added PYTHONPATH to my system environment. What I'd like to do, is remove that for the purposes of the virtualenv. Unfortunately, I have no idea how to **do** that:

1. What file do I edit?
2. Where?
3. Is there a way to do this so that, in the future when I start a virtualenv, I don't have to similarly edit whatever I'm going to have to edit to fix this problem (this problem has been happening for long enough that I imagine it has been solved)?
4. Should I be using `virtualenvwrapper` to help me here (I've seen that referenced in respect of this problem a number of times)?
5. Generally: halp?

As I understand it, the steps are:

- Install virtualenv: check
- Create a virtualenv using the --no-site-packages flag: check
- pip freeze: what the? All these packages!!
- figure out how to remove PYTHONPATH from virtualenv: I have no idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that there is a virtualenv bug when you have a $ in the path name. Who knew?

Answer (score 1):

Have you entered the virtualenv before `pip freeze`?

```
virtualenv --no-site-packages .venv  # create virtualenv
source .venv/bin/activate  # enter virtualenv
```

**Edit**

If you want to change environmental variable in your virtualenv, you can try editing virtualenv's `activate` script. It is located in `virtualenvdir/bin/activate`

Comment: ya, I did that... no dice sadly. If you look at the linked posts, it's not a unique problem, I just don't know how to 'do' the solution(s).

Answer (score 1):

There's also a bug where spaces in any directories leading to your virtual environment will cause pip to not be found